# Vectorized/Matrix calculation between 2 Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, difflib

I'm using the difflib ratio to calculate the similarity between 2 strings:

```
ratio = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'string1', 'string2').ratio()
```

The output is a single float value from 0-1 which can be interpreted as the match score.

What I'm trying to do is create a column which contains the best match based on `max(ratio)` between the value and a list of other values.

So if:

```
df.col1 = 'maria','fred','john'
```

and:

```
df2.col1 = 'mary','orange','maria'
```

`df.bestmatch` would contain the best match for `'maria', 'fred' and 'john'` based on the `df2.col1` values.

I feel like this is possible using the `.apply` method, but I just can't wrap my head around how to calculate each value in `df.col1` against `df2.col1`.

UPDATE: the difflib.get_close_matches method was able to handle large arrays much better and gave me everything I wanted except the ratio score (not a big deal). Tom's answer below worked for smaller datasets, but got a MemoryError when each column was ~19,000 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited in response to your comment:

```
In [164]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['maria','fred','john'], 'col2': ['mary','orange','maria']})
```

Makes all the combos (maria, mary), (maria, orange), (maria, maria), (fred ...)

```
In [165]: combos = itertools.product(df.col1, df.col2)
```

`combos` will be a flat list of tuples like `('maria', 'mary') ...,` 9 in total. Since we need the best match for each name we need to group the tuples by the name from `col1`.

```
In [166]: groups = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(combos, lambda x: x[0])]
```

Now we have a list of three lists: `[[('maria', 'mary'), ('maria', 'orange'), ('maria', 'maria')], [...]]`. The second argument to `groupby` is the key that breaks up the groups. Check out the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
In [167]: groups
Out[167]: 
[[('maria', 'mary'), ('maria', 'orange'), ('maria', 'maria')],
 [('fred', 'mary'), ('fred', 'orange'), ('fred', 'maria')],
 [('john', 'mary'), ('john', 'orange'), ('john', 'maria')]]
```

Define a helper function:

```
def get_best(group):
    k = group[0][0]
    ratios = {x[1]: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, *x).ratio() for x in group}
    winner = max(ratios.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    return winner[1] # mess with this to return original name, mathcihng name, ratio
```

This is the function you'll apply to each of the lists in `groups`. Just like before we hand of the pair to `SequenceMatcher` to get the ratio. Only now we need to keep the name around. So in that function `x` is a tuple like `('maria', 'mary')`. We need to know the name in the best match and the ratio of the best match, so I threw them in a dict with `{name: ratio}`.  The other thing here is that `max` takes a second argument. This time it's just saying the thing to maximize is `x[1]`, the ratio.

And get the best matches:

```
In [173]: best = [get_best(group) for group in groups]

In [175]: df['best_match'] = best

In [176]: df
Out[176]: 
    col1    col2 best_match
0  maria    mary      maria
1   fred  orange     orange
2   john   maria     orange

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

This should be fairly efficient.

Comment: Hey Tom, this gets me closer--but what I'm after is the col2 value with the highest ratio. So for example maria would be evaluated against mary, orange, maria and sam, then based on the ratio score, maria would be returned. Next fred would be evaluated against the same values and the value with the highest score will be returned and so on. Does that make sense?  This can probably be done with some ugly nested for loops, but I'm hoping for a more elegant/efficient solution.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty complex. Is there not a simpler way? I feel uncomfortable using code where I don't understand 90% of what's going on...

Comment: Just added some comments. Hopefully they help! There might be a simpler way, but when you break the problem down I think everything here is needed. First create the list of all matches (`combos`). Then break that list up by name from `df.col1` (`groups`). Finally, get the name and ratio that's the best match for each name (`get_best`). line `[173]` could be done with a `df.col1.apply(get_best)`.

Comment: Hey Tom, I got around to trying your solution but got a MemoryError when creating the groups object. For reference each df column contains about 15,000 values...

Comment: I just found that the difflib.get_close_matches method does pretty much what I want.